# Echo inside mysql statement?

Tags: mysql, printing, echo

Is it possible **to echo** inside a MySQL statement?

For example:

`SELECT
p.ID,p.post_title,p.guid,p.post_name,p.post_status,name,taxonomy,
<?php echo "TEXT HERE"?> GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name ORDER BY name DESC SEPARATOR '|') AS 'tags',`

Is this possible to get this result **{tag1|tag2|tag3}** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358300/mysql-join-group-concat-second-table) might be relevant. However this should do what you want:

```
-- Table structure:
-- post(_id_), tag (_id_, tag), post_tag(post*, tag*)

SELECT post.id,
    CONCAT('{', GROUP_CONCAT(distinct tag.tag order by tag.tag separator '}{'), '}') AS tags
FROM post
JOIN post_tag ON post.id = post_tag.post
JOIN tag ON post_tag.tag = tag.id
GROUP BY post.id
```

Which returns:

```
+----+--------+
| id | tags   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | {A}{B} |
|  2 | {B}{C} |
|  3 | {C}    |
+----+--------+
```

Make sure to include the `GROUP BY` clause. I did add foreign key references but I'm unsure whether MySQL actually uses them for this.

Comment: Wow thanks sir it works like a charm THANK YOU VERY MUCH very interesting. I admit I have difficulties on queries thank you very much sir :)

Comment: No problem, I hadn't heard of `GROUP_CONCAT` before today, so I've learned something new too :)

Comment: wow such a pleasure sir we both learned in this topic thanks again sir you made my day cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're writing this query in PHP to execute in MySQL, you can either enclose the SQL in double quotes, which will cause variables to be parsed:

```
$sql = " SELECT p.ID ... taxonomy, $someVariable GROUP_CONCAT ... ";
```

or (preferred IMO) use single quotes and concatenate it in (also makes it easier to clean it inline, as shown here)

```
$sql = ' SELECT p.ID ... taxonomy, ' . mysql_real_escape_string($someVariable) . ' GROUP_CONCAT ... ';
```

Comment: thanks for the reply sir but ross took exactly what Im looking for thanks sir