# SQL Help ~ GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-concat

I have a problem incorporating a Group_Concat function in my SQL query.  I have tried to work around it with PHP, but I would prefer to get it right with SQL instead.  My code is below, I am using the latest version of MYSQL.

```
SELECT Main.Title, Main.DatePrint, Main.PerformanceDate, Main.Unsure_Sure, Main.Register, Main.notes, 
VenueKey.Venue,AuthorKey.Author, CompanyKey.Company, PrintKey.Printer, SourceKey.Source 
FROM Main INNER JOIN MainVenue
    ON Main.MainID = MainVenue.ID_V
    INNER JOIN VenueKey
    ON MainVenue.VenueID = VenueKey.ID_V_K

    INNER JOIN MainAuthor
    ON Main.MainID = MainAuthor.ID_A
    INNER JOIN AuthorKey
    ON MainAuthor.AuthorID = AuthorKey.ID_A_K

    INNER JOIN MainCompany
    ON Main.MainID = MainCompany.ID_C
    INNER JOIN CompanyKey
    ON MainCompany.CompanyID = CompanyKey.ID_C_K

    INNER JOIN MainPrinter
    ON Main.MainID = MainPrinter.ID_P
    INNER JOIN PrintKey
    ON MainPrinter.PrinterID = PrintKey.ID_P_K

    INNER JOIN MainSource
    ON Main.MainID = MainSource.ID_S
    INNER JOIN SourceKey
    ON MainSource.SourceID = SourceKey.ID_S_K
```

Ideally I would like to use a Group_Concat on Author, Venue, and Company but I have been having a hard time getting it to work, with it instead returning a null value.  Please let me know what if there is anything I can do to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a GROUP_BY clause? GROUP_CONCAT only works when something is being grouped

Comment: Hello, no I am not using a GROUP_BY, I just have not put the GROUP_CONCAT in the code above.  I was trying to use the GROUP_CONCAT in the SELECT statement

Comment: Well, you can only use `GROUP_CONCAT()` if you actually `GROUP` your DB results. Maybe you need the `CONCAT()` function? Depends on what you actually want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be grouping the results in order for GROUP_CONCAT to have something to work with. Try something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
  AuthorKey.Author,
  GROUP_CONCAT(VenueKey.Venue) AS all_venues,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CompanyKey.Company) AS all_companies
...
GROUP BY AuthorKey.Author
```

to get a list of the authors with a concatenated list of venues and companies for example.

Comment: Hey, I tried implementing this, but my query seems to refuse to work with the Group_Concat function.  Even the Group By addition by itself resulted in an error.  Is there any reason for this not to work within my query structure?

Comment: I can't see any reason why adding a GROUP BY clause would cause an error. What is the error?

Comment: I guess I do not know what the error is exactly, but my error handler for no results comes up when, according to the search parameters, I know there are results there.

Answer (score 0):

This post solved my problem.  I also revisited my `SELECT` statement and adjusted it.

[MySQL JOIN / GROUP_CONCAT second table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358300/mysql-join-group-concat-second-table)